# Test a react component from an async function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

i'm trying to test with jest and enzyme a component that's returned from an async function but i have problems building it

```
async function action() {
  return {
    chunks: ['something'],
    title: 'something',
    component: (
      <Layout>
        <Something_else />
      </Layout>
    ),
  };
}
export default action;
```

and my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import index from './index.js';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

it('Snapshot test', () => {
        const i = index();
        i.then((r) => {

            const ccc = React.createClass({
                render() {
                   return r.component;
                   }
             })

             const wrapper = mount(<ccc />);

            expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('err');
        });
    });
```

the problem is that in my snapshot all i get is a line saying "`<ccc />`", isn't mount supposed to expand the component to at least show it's children?